# Choices Without Side By Side Duplicates

Tags: python, list

Hi! I am trying to print a list of letters (this list will never change) where duplicates are allowed but just not side by side that start with the same letter, but I need a set number of results, let's say 14 for this example. The below is what I have.

letters = ["A", "AAA", "B", "BBB", "C", "CCC", "D", "DDD", "E", "EEE"]                                                      groups = random.choices(letters, k = 14)                                                                                                print(groups)

Example return: ['B', 'CCC', 'AAA', 'A', 'EEE', 'D', 'DDD', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'E', 'AAA', 'BBB']                   Which is not great due to having 'AAA', 'A'--'D', 'DDD'---'B', 'B' next to each other.

Hope for something like this: ['B', 'CCC', 'A', 'BBB', 'EEE', 'D', 'AAA', 'B', 'E', 'B', 'CCC', 'E', 'AAA', 'BBB']    Where each string starts with a letter different than the one to the right / left of it.

Comment: Change your start data, because it looks like it's actually `["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]` and you want to generate either 1 or 3 of those, at a time, which makes it a lot easier to pick a letter, "generate either 1 or 3", and then pick a _different_ letter.

Comment: Please repost your code with proper formatting and indentation. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting Don't use HTML formatting.

Comment: Roger that, will do here in a bit after some meetings I need to attend, thanks for the link.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Choose the strings one by one, and check each time if the first letter is different from the first letter of the last chosen string - if it isn't, just keep on trying other random choices.

```
import random

letters = ["A", "AAA", "B", "BBB", "C", "CCC", "D", "DDD", "E", "EEE"]                 

expected_length = 14
out = []
for _ in range(expected_length):
    while True:
        new = random.choice(letters)
        if not out or new[0] != out[-1][0]:
            out.append(new)
            break
print(out)
#  ['C', 'AAA', 'EEE', 'D', 'CCC', 'D', 'AAA', 'DDD', 'C', 'E', 'A', 'BBB', 'EEE', 'AAA']
```

Comment: This was AMAZING! It was perfect for what I was presenting. It actually got me to re-look at my code and do some thinking. I have some upcoming twists to my listed issue here & with this, I think I MIGHT be able to tackle those twists on my own :) First I need to study your layout and get to where I fully understand what exactly is happening & why (which I will). The good news is I generally understand what's going on with it so it shouldn't take me too long to break it down and follow it step by step. I thought one could 'Accept' multiple answers but obviously I thought wrong:) Thanks much !

Answer (score 1):

Make a 2-dimensional list. Each nested list consists of strings that start with the same letter.

Then you can shuffle the top-level list to get a random order of starting letters, and select a random element from each sublist.

```
letters = [["A", "AAA"], ["B", "BBB"], ["C", "CCC"], ["D", "DDD"], ["E", "EEE"]]
last_letter = None
result = []
for i in range(14):
    if i % len(letters) == 0:
        while True:
            # Reshuffle letters, making sure the first letter isn't the same as the last letter we used
            random.shuffle(letters)
            if letters[0][0] != last_letter:
                break
    letter = random.choice(letters[i%len(letters)])
    last_letter = letter[0]
    result.append(letter)

print(result)
```

Comment: This was fantastic as well!  It too is exactly what I needed.  So obviously I'm in the beginning stages of learning Python and while I am generally familiar with your code, putting it all together just wasn't going to happen any time soon if left up to me :) So this was great.  I need to study both answers given see how they both end with the same result.  They are a good comparison for me though.  Think I can learn a lot from comparing the two.  Thanks a lot for assistance !